# 10'' tablet 1280x800 with MDPI screen reads values data from values-sw800dp-xhdpi instead of values-sw800dp-mdpi?

Tags: android, screen, device, mdpi

I just want to admit that there are folder for landscape for the both devices as well called `values-sw800dp-land-mdpi` and `values-sw800dp-land-xhdpi`. The other two folders are for Portrait orientation.

Android version 4.0.3.

Comment: what version of android is your tablet running?